# Comments on Author page

Tags: comments, author-template

**Update:**

Ok,the DEBUG log  says:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3105

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3939

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3941

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3943

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3944

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3952

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/content/00/8437600/html/test/wp-includes/query.php on line 3967
```

**NOTE:**

At the top of my `author.php` I use the following code in order to get user meta for the page:

```
<? $curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug',    
    get_query_var('author_name')) :    
    get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
?>
```

**End of update**

**Original Post**

First - I am teaching myself how to write php and am also new to this forum.

I am trying to follow the instructions from the top answer for this question [Author page: Comments and Ratings?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/author-page-comments-and-ratings) to add  comments to author.php - without any luck.

The following is the steps I have taken:

1. Created a custom post type to hold the comments
2. Created a new post in said post type
3. Created custom field in user meta called -> author_post_id
4. Added newly created post id to user meta for particular user Note: this works because I can add echo statement in the code provided and the above link and it echos the correct post id so I know I did something write (lol)
5. Copy/pasted the code given on the above link (answer #3) into my author.php

Nothing is showing up.  What am I missing?

I even added `wp_reset_query();` after the loop that displays post by the author and it made no difference.

Here is my test author page http://test.thesingleparentperspective.com/author/ckmatthews/

Comment: Have you enabled [debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)?

Comment: This really shows my newbiness but no - I don't know how.

Comment: Then follow the link and follow the instructions :)

Comment: Please clean up the question. It is now a bit confusing. You do not need to keep information that is no longer relevant.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Are you notified when I update the original post?

Comment: Not on the update, no. And yes, that is better. Since you are new here, think about this. The Stack is not a support forum. While it looks like one, it functions more like a Wiki. Questions should be clean and clear even if that mean a major rewrite.

Comment: I understand, and I do appreciate your time and input.