# Allowing comments on author pages

Tags: comments, author-template

I need to be able to allow users to leave comments on author profile pages.

I came across another answer here that has given me a basic outline of what needs to be done to allow it:

- [Author page: Comments and Ratings?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/author-page-comments-and-ratings)

That said, I am unsure how to proceed with getting it implemented. I have created a custom post type to hold the comments, but I do not know how to make it so that each time a user/author signs up to our site (we are building a site with open registration), a post gets created in the custom post type to hold comments, and then automatically associated to their user profile.

Would much appreciate a more detailed answer than what was provided on the linked question, so that I am able to understand exactly how to get this up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form  unless I'm mistaken, you will need to add this to your author.php file. If your using a theme that gets updated your will have to make a plugin out of it.

```
<?php comment_form( $args, $post_id ); ?>
```

Comment: Yes it goes without saying that the comment form will need to be added to author.php - this is covered in the answer I provided a link to.